# Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.params' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, express, parameters, undefined, middleware

I want my middleware to check if the user is the author of the ad to allow him to edit the post.
My middleware is defined as

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const { carSchema } = require("./schemas.js");
const Car = require("./models/car");

module.exports.isAuthor = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next, Model) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const document = await Model.findById(id);
  if (!document.author.equals(req.user._id)) {
    req.flash("error", "Not allowed");
    return res.redirect(`/${Model.collection.name}/${id}`);
  }
  next();
});
```

Router is defined as:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const Car = require("../models/car");
const { isLoggedIn, isAuthor, validateCar } = require("../middleware");

router.get(
  "/:id/edit",
  isLoggedIn,
  isAuthor.bind(null, Car),
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!car) {
      req.flash("error", "This ad doesnt exist");
      return res.redirect("/cars");
    }
    res.render("cars/editCar", { car });
  })
);
```

When trying to edit the add I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.params' as it is undefined.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.params' as it is undefined. at middleware.js:26:11 at asyncUtilWrap (node_modules\express-async-handler\index.js:3:20) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at next (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13) at module.exports.isLoggedIn (middleware.js:11:3) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at next (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13) at Route.dispatch (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15 >
```

How to make isAuthor middleware reusable regardless of the model?

Comment: `isAuthor.bind(null, Car),`  You've pretty much killed the `req, res, next` with this.

Comment: `bind` binds (after the zeroth) the first, not the last, parameter